# Custom NPM script, which calls multiple NPM scripts, doesn't stop on failure

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I'm creating a custom npm script to alert developers to upgrade their version of node. The script uses please-upgrade-node (basically their example) and returns an exit code of 0:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var pkg = require('./package.json');
var pleaseUpgradeNode = require('please-upgrade-node');

pleaseUpgradeNode(pkg, {
  exitCode: 1,
  message: function(requiredVersion) {
    return ('ERROR!! This program requires Node version' +  requiredVersion');
  }
});
```

Here's the output when I run `node please-upgrade-node` in the console:

```
ERROR!! This program requires Node version10.10.0
```

Here are my npm scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "pun": "node please-upgrade-node",
  "build": "webpack",
  "dev": "webpack-dev-server --open",
  "start:dev": "npm run pun & npm run build & npm run dev"
}
```

The issue is when I run `npm run start:dev` it'll state I need to use a newer version of node but the subsequent scripts will still run starting the dev server for webpack.

I thought NPM would cancel the entire `start:dev` script but that doesn't seem to be the case. Here's the output after `npm run start:dev`:

```
> companyInfoHere@0.0.1 start:dev /Users/companyInfoHere
> npm run pun & npm run build & npm run dev


> companyInfoHere@0.0.1 pun /Users/companyInfoHere
> node please-upgrade-node


> companyInfoHere@0.0.1 build /Users/companyInfoHere
> webpack


> companyInfoHere@0.0.1 dev /Users/companyInfoHere
> webpack-dev-server --open

ERROR!! This program requires Node version10.10.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! companyInfoHere@0.0.1 pun: `node please-upgrade-node`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the companyInfoHere@0.0.1 pun script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/companyInfoHere/.npm/_logs/2018-12-07T17_39_32_580Z-debug.log

clean-webpack-plugin: /Users/companyInfoHere/dist has been removed.
clean-webpack-plugin: /Users/companyInfoHere/dist has been removed.
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8081/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /dist/js/
ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /dist/js/main.js
Hash: d84005de56ec80ce9d06
Version: webpack 4.27.1
Time: 2124ms
Built at: 12/07/2018 12:27:33 PM
        Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
      main.js   816 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
  main.js.map   944 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
manifest.json  76 bytes          [emitted]
Entrypoint main = main.js main.js.map
[./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/index.tsx] 189 bytes {main} [built]
    + 13 hidden modules
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 2e79b1121cc06c02ad0d
Version: webpack 4.27.1
Time: 2576ms
Built at: 12/07/2018 12:27:34 PM
        Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
      main.js  1.11 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
  main.js.map  1.29 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
manifest.json  76 bytes          [emitted]
Entrypoint main = main.js main.js.map
[0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 ./src/index.tsx 40 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/ansi-html/index.js] 4.16 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js] 135 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js] 7.68 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/react-dom/index.js] 1.33 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/react/index.js] 190 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] 161 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/url/url.js] 22.8 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:8081] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 7.78 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.58 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 75 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/components/app.tsx] 203 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/index.tsx] 189 bytes {main} [built]
    + 24 hidden modules
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

I'm using the following packages:

[please-upgrade-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/please-upgrade-node)

[webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack)

[webpack-dev-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-server)

edit: added the correct exit code in example and change console response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the double ampersand(`&&`) not the Single ampersand `&`.

```
"scripts": {
  "pun": "node please-upgrade-node",
  "build": "webpack",
  "dev": "webpack-dev-server --open",
  "start:dev": "npm run pun && npm run build && npm run dev"
}
```

`&` means running process in background and `&&` means AND operator if the left hand command succeeds it will run the right hand command. Which is what you basically want.